# How do you "stack" flex elements that are in seperated columns?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax, flexbox

I've displayed my elements using the flex property and flex-flow: column nowrap. I've made quick display of what my elements look like :[this]

[image]

So obviously I can't just stack both of the column on top of each other because I'm using ajax call to number each element, my left column is for even number and the right one for odd numbers. I'm wondering how I could achieve this without breaking my code. I'm doing this so that it can be responsive for mobile users.

Comment: You want your elements look like on the picture? Or what?

Comment: Sorry if I wasen't clear enough, the picture is what I've done. Now I want both columns to be one? So that all the elements are on top of each other for mobile.

Answer (score 0):

I dont get why you want to do it this way?

You could just make it into rows, with a placeholder that you remove, when screen size gets to small. That way, you can keep it all simple and clean.

```
- container
-- row
--- box
--- placeholder
--- box
--- placeholder
```

Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/d9jg1p2s/

---

**EDIT:** Forgot to remove placeholders on mobile size.
Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/d9jg1p2s/1/

Answer (score 0):

There is no method to *merge* containers in flexbox but there is a method for the containers to be treated as though they were not there.

It's `display:contents`

> Browsers (excepting Firefox) will remove any element with a display value of contents set on it from the accessibility tree. This will cause the element and all its descendant elements to no longer be announced by screen reading technology.
>
> <sup>[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display)</sup>

[**Support**](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-display-contents), unfortuately, is not universal but is growing.

Then..just align each alternate element in the "new" column to   `align-self: flex-end;`

```css
* {   margin: 0;   padding: 0;   box-sizing: border-box; }  ::before, ::after {   box-sizing:inherit; }

.box {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
  border:2px solid rebeccapurple;
}

body {
  width: 55%;
  min-width:150px;
  margin:1em auto;
  border:1px solid limegreen;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.box:nth-child(odd) {
  align-self: flex-end;
}

.container {
  display:contents;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">1</div>
  <div class="box">3</div>
  <div class="box">5</div>
  <div class="box">7</div>
  <div class="box">9</div>
  <div class="box">11</div>

</div>

<div class="container">

  <div class="box">2</div>
  <div class="box">4</div>
  <div class="box">6</div>
  <div class="box">8</div>
  <div class="box">10</div>
  <div class="box">12</div>
</div>
```